# Prove if A and B are n x n upper triangular matrices, so is AB

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm trying to practice proofs for my linear algebra final and I've been stuck on this one for some time.

I have $AB = [A\mathbf{b_1} \ A\mathbf{b_2} \ \dots \ A\mathbf{b_n}]$. I can show that $A\mathbf{b_1}$ has the form $\left(
\begin{array}{c} a_{11} b_{11} \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{array}
\right)$
and that $A\mathbf{b_2}$ has the form  $\left(
\begin{array}{c} a_{11} b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22} \\
a_{22}b_{22} \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{array}
\right)$ but I'm not sure how to generalize this. Would proof by induction be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ and  $B=(b_{ij})$. Since $B$ is upper triangular then

$$Be_j=\sum_{i=1}^{j} b_{ij}e_i$$
and since $A$ is also upper traingular then

$$AB e_j=\sum_{i=1}^jb_{ij}Ae_i=\sum_{i=1}^jb_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^ia_{ki}e_k=\sum_{k=1}^j\sum_{i=k}^jb_{ij}a_{ki}e_k=\sum_{k=1}^jc_{kj}e_k$$
which means that $AB$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the $ij$-th ($i$-th row, $j$-th column) element of $A$ by $A_{ij}$, we have that $A_{ij}=0$ if $i>j$. The same holds for $B$ with the notation $B_{ij}$

Now if $i>j$:

$$(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{ik}B_{kj}=\sum_{k=i}^{n}A_{ik}B_{kj}$$

But if $k≥i>j$ then $k>j$ and hence $B_{kj}=0$. This gives $(AB)_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$, i.e. $AB$ is upper triangular.